# Why cout complaining when calling a function from an object of other class?

Tags: c++, ios, c++11

I have these composition classes below. 
 Problem is, in Elephant.cpp, the line:
     cout<<"Elephant do: \n"<

Practice62.cpp this is the main class

```
#include < iostream >
#include "Animal.h"
#include "Elephant.h"

int main()
{
    Animal an;
    Elephant el(an);
    el.shout();

}
```

// Animal.cpp: animal class

```
#include "Animal.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Animal::Animal()
{
   cout<<"Animal constructor"<<endl;
}

void Animal::eats()
{
 cout<<"eats"<<endl;
}
void Animal::sleeps()
{
 cout<<"sleeps"<<endl;
}

//Animal.h Animal header

#ifndef ANIMAL_H
#define ANIMAL_H
class Animal
{
 public:
        Animal();
        void eats();
        void sleeps();

};


//Elephant.cpp Elephant class definition

#include <iostream>
#include "Elephant.h"
#include "Animal.h"

using namespace std;

Elephant::Elephant(Animal an)
: animal(an)
{
}

void Elephant::shout()
{
 cout<<"Elephant do: \n"<<animal.eats();

}
```

// Elephant.h: Elephant header

```
#ifndef ELEPHANT_H
#define ELEPHANT_H
#include <iostream>
#include "Animal.h"

using namespace std;

class Elephant
{
  public:
         Elephant(Animal an);
         void shout();
  private:
          Animal animal;
};
#endif
```

Can someone explain why cout won't accept this calling of function within <

Comment: Because `cout` can't print `void`. Return a `char*` or `std::string` instead.

Comment: And there was really no way for you to minimize your example *a bit*? 10 lines in a single file should have been plenty.

Answer (score 0):

The signature of the function you invoke in your `cout` line is

```
void eats();
```

This means that it returns no value, and in consequence `cout` has nothing to display.

Solve this issue and change the problmetic function to:

```
void Elephant::shout()
{
     cout<<"Elephant do: \n"; 
     animal.eats();  // has its own cout
}
```